# MinionPro and csquotes spacing problem

Tags: kerning, csquotes, minionpro

I am using `MinionPro` with `csquotes`. I have noticed that when creating a quote within a quote with `\enquote{\enquote{text}}`, whereupon the outer double and the inner single quotation marks fall together, there is no space between the quotation marks with `MinionPro`. In comparison, when using `lmodern` there is an extra space.

Is there a solution for this problem using `\enquote{\enquote{text}}`, favourably without adding the extra space manually each time a quote within a quote occurs?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
%\usepackage{lmodern} % kerning in all examples, but larger spaces with \enquote{}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\enquote{\enquote{This is a quote within a quote.}} % no spacing for Minion Pro

\enquote{{}\enquote{This is a quote within a quote.}{}} % still no spacing for Minion Pro

\enquote{{}`This is a quote within a quote.'{}} % possible solution

``{}`This is a quote within a quote.'{}'' % correct result without \enquote{}

\end{document}
```

Result with `MinionPro`:
[image: minionpro]

Result with `lmodern`:
[image: lmodern]

Comment: I don't have minionpro and so can't test. What happens if you add `\makeatletter 

\def\csq@addkern@close{%
  \ifdim\lastkern=\csq@kernmarker
    \unkern\unkern
    \ifdim\csq@thekern@close=\z@
    \else
      \penalty\@M\hskip1cm\relax
    \fi
  \fi}
` to your document? Do you get a large space between the both quotes?

Comment: You can't comment on your own post because you're using a different account. Accounts can be merged, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: The only reason I can imagine why there should be no spacing is a zero em parameter -- and this is quite improbable. What do you get `x\hspace{1em}y`? Is there a sensible large space?

Comment: Yes, there is. Regarding your first comment, I do get a large space between the both quotes. Is it likely that this is an intended feature of `MinionPro` or could it be a bug?

Comment: I have just noticed that, interestingly, there is the desired space between the quotation marks using `\enquote{\enquote{text}}` when compiling my document with xelatex. I installed`MinionPro` for pdflatex using the [MPro-Installation-Guide](https://github.com/henrikgit/MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub) since I couldn't get [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) to work. Could anyone with a FontPro install of `MinionPro` try to replicate this?

Comment: To answer my own question: The problem does also occur with a FontPro install of `MinionPro` on a different system (Linux instead of Windows). So this seems to be an idiosyncrasy of the font design.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because op states it's a font design loophole